# Building x64 NSIS (using VS2012)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nsis, zlib, scons

I am in the process of creating a pure x64 version of my application.  In order to do that, I also need an x64 installer.  I've read online that the NSIS code does support x64 but since they don't distribute an x64 build that I need to build from source (including all plugins/etc).

I've been able to build NSIS (v3.0.4) from source for x86 using Python 2.7/SCons 3.1.1/VS 2012/Zlib 1.2.7.

```
scons ZLIB_W32=C:\Source\zlib-1.2.7
```

But when I add the TARGET_ARCH=amd64 to the scons command,

```
scons ZLIB_W32=C:\Source\zlib-1.2.7 TARGET_ARCH=amd64
```

It doesn't work.  Initially it built but didn't link because zlib was still x86.

```
C:\Source\zlib-1.2.7\lib\zdll.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
```

However, after rebuilding zlib1.dll (using VS2012) to be x64 (dumpbin confirms this)

I now get an error that it can't find zlib

```
scons ZLIB_W32=C:\Source\zlib-1.2.7 TARGET_ARCH=amd64
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
WARNING: VER_PACKED not set, defaulting to 0x03003666!
Delete("nsis-18-Nov-2019.cvs")
Delete(".instdist")
Delete(".test")
Using Microsoft tools configuration (14.2)
Checking for memset requirement... (cached) yes
Checking for memcpy requirement... (cached) yes
Checking for C library gdi32... (cached) yes
Checking for C library user32... (cached) yes
Checking for C library pthread... (cached) no
Checking for C library iconv... (cached) no
Checking for C library shlwapi... (cached) yes
Checking for C library oleaut32... (cached) yes
Checking for C library version... (cached) yes
Checking for C library zdll... no
Checking for C library z... no
zlib (win32) is missing!
```

Note that I have made sure that the directory structure matches in the x64 build so that the following files exist:

```
C:\Source\zlib-1.2.7\zlib1.dll
C:\Source\zlib-1.2.7\lib\zlib1.lib
C:\Source\zlib-1.2.7\include\zconf.h
C:\Source\zlib-1.2.7\include\zlib.h
```

It did occur to me that I'm telling scons to look for x86 zlib (hence the W32 in ZLIB_W32) but I didn't see an option for telling scons to look for x64 zlib in the -h output.

What am I missing?

-UPDATE 1-
I'm making progress but not out of the woods yet.  I've identified several issues with my build.  #1, I wasn't actually using VS2012 like I thought (I have several versions installed).  See above where the scons output says 14.0 (VS2019).  Oops.  Unfortunately, simply adding a MSVC_VERSION=11.0 to my command line didn't fix it.  It seems that the nsis project isn't passing this along to scons.  The only way I could figure out how to do this was to modify the nsis SConstruct file from:

```
######################################################################
#######  Build Environment                                         ###
######################################################################

path = ARGUMENTS.get('PATH', '')
toolset = ARGUMENTS.get('TOOLSET', '')
arch = ARGUMENTS.get('TARGET_ARCH', 'x86')

if toolset and path:
    defenv = Environment(TARGET_ARCH = arch, ENV = {'PATH' : path}, TOOLS = toolset.split(',') + ['zip'])
else:
    if path:
        defenv = Environment(TARGET_ARCH = arch, ENV = {'PATH' : path})
    if toolset:
        defenv = Environment(TARGET_ARCH = arch, TOOLS = toolset.split(',') + ['zip'])
if not toolset and not path:
    defenv = Environment(TARGET_ARCH = arch)

Export('defenv')
```

to:

```
######################################################################
#######  Build Environment                                         ###
######################################################################

path = ARGUMENTS.get('PATH', '')
toolset = ARGUMENTS.get('TOOLSET', '')
arch = ARGUMENTS.get('TARGET_ARCH', 'x86')
vs_version = ARGUMENTS.get('MSVC_VERSION', '')

if toolset and path:
    defenv = Environment(TARGET_ARCH = arch, ENV = {'PATH' : path}, TOOLS = toolset.split(',') + ['zip'], MSVC_VERSION = vs_version)
else:
    if path:
        defenv = Environment(TARGET_ARCH = arch, ENV = {'PATH' : path}, MSVC_VERSION = vs_version)
    if toolset:
        defenv = Environment(TARGET_ARCH = arch, TOOLS = toolset.split(',') + ['zip'], MSVC_VERSION = vs_version)
if not toolset and not path:
    defenv = Environment(TARGET_ARCH = arch, MSVC_VERSION = vs_version)

Export('defenv')
```

Now my build output correctly identifies as VS2012:

```
C:\Source\nsis\nsis-code-r7069-NSIS-tags-v304>scons ZLIB_W32=C:\Source\zlib MSVC_VERSION=11.0
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
WARNING: VER_PACKED not set, defaulting to 0x03003666!
Delete("nsis-19-Nov-2019.cvs")
Delete(".instdist")
Delete(".test")
Using Microsoft tools configuration (11.0)
Checking for memset requirement... (cached) yes
<snip>
```

It seems like there should be a better way to allow this but I'm not familiar enough (yet) with scons or nsis's usage of it to submit a PR to fix this.  Or maybe it already exists and I'm just not smart enough to find it (yet).

Now, on to building x64 nsis.  Big thanks to @Anders for narrowing down which files are needed a bit and @bdbaddog for suggesting to look into the scons config.log where I found that I had named the zlib.dll lib file incorrectly when I build it for x64.  After changing the output lib to

```
C:\Source\zlib-1.2.7\lib\zdll.lib
```

It at least tries to build but fails at linking...

-edit to update 1-  all of the linking errors that were here previously were a bad rabbit hole I went down yesterday.  Not sure if it was caused by scons leaving some temp files somewhere or VS doing it or me just being stupid but today when I started trying to track down the linking errors I couldn't reproduce them (there was a machine reboot yesterday and who knows what might have been locked/cached until then).

-UPDATE 2-
This update is removing all the mis-leading crap from update 1.  Current situation is x64 NSIS build (using both my zlib-1.2.7-amd64 build AND the official NSIS zlib-1.2.8-amd64 pre-built binaries on the NSIS wiki) is failing at linking with the same error:

```
System.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol CallProc2 referenced in function Call
build\urelease\System\amd64-unicode\System.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
scons: *** [build\urelease\System\amd64-unicode\System.dll] Error 1120
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

So far I'm not having any luck figuring out what CallProc2 is but I think this means zlib is no longer at fault here.

-UPDATE 3-
Thanks to @Anders for the direction here since I was really stumped on the Callproc issue, the CallProc2 method is isolated to the system plugin and is caused by it not building correctly.  There is some discussion in the comments below trying to find the cause but for now, I'm just excluding that plugin to get to a system that works before coming back to this.

Right now, the scons build completes and produces x64 binaries.

```
C:\Source\nsis\build\urelease\makensisw\>dumpbin /HEADERS ./makensisw.exe
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 11.00.61030.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file ./makensisw.exe

PE signature found

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

FILE HEADER VALUES
            8664 machine (x64)
```

However, the installer build now results in the following error:

```
scons dist-installer ZLIB_W32=C:\Source\zlib-1.2.8-x64 MSVC_VERSION=11.0
link /nologo /map /subsystem:console,5.01 /OUT:build\urelease\VPatch\Source\GenPat\GenPat.exe /LIBPATH:C:\Source\zlib-1.2.8-x64\lib zdll.lib build\urelease\VPatch\Source\GenPat\adler32.obj build\urelease\VPatch\Source\GenPat\Checksums.obj build\urelease\VPatch\Source\GenPat\ChunkedFile.obj build\urelease\VPatch\Source\GenPat\FileFormat1.obj build\urelease\VPatch\Source\GenPat\GlobalTypes.obj build\urelease\VPatch\Source\GenPat\main.obj build\urelease\VPatch\Source\GenPat\md5.obj build\urelease\VPatch\Source\GenPat\PatchGenerator.obj build\urelease\VPatch\Source\GenPat\POSIXUtil.obj
adler32.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _adler32 referenced in function "unsigned long __cdecl Checksum::adler32(unsigned long,unsigned char const *,unsigned int)" (?adler32@Checksum@@YAKKPBEI@Z)
build\urelease\VPatch\Source\GenPat\GenPat.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
scons: *** [build\urelease\VPatch\Source\GenPat\GenPat.exe] Error 1120
```

Unfortunately, without the installer, I'm kinda lost again.  The x64 binaries run but when trying to compile any script (I believe), I get the following error (note that I copied makensis and zlib1.dll into the same directory for this):

```
C:\Source>makensis.exe ./myapp.nsi
Error: reading stub "C:\Stubs\zlib-amd64-unicode"
Error initalizing CEXEBuild: error setting default stub
```

-UPDATE 4-
I have finally gotten a build to work successfully after ignoring the system plugin.  This works both with compiling zlib from source for x64 or with the prebuilt version from the NSIS wiki (linked in @Anders answer below):

```
scons ZLIB_W32=C:\Source\zlib-1.2.8-x64 TARGET_ARCH=amd64 MSVC_VERSION=11.0 SKIPPLUGINS=System
```

and I was able to deploy to my dev system using (from an admin enabled prompt since I was installing to Program Files):

```
scons PREFIX="C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS" install ZLIB_W32=C:\Source\zlib-1.2.8-x64 TARGET_ARCH=amd64 SKIPPLUGINS=System
```

Unfortunately, you cannot build the NSIS installer from here (dist-install) because the NSIS installer itself apparently depends on usage of the System plugin.  So this scenario isn't sufficient for being able to prep a build machine unless you are going to build everything from scratch on that machine.

Also, I'm not out of the woods yet because I also use the System plugin for my installer so I need to figure out why that isn't working.

However, I was able to compile and run a pure x64 bare minimum installer package with the above setup:

```
# name the installer
OutFile "Installer.exe"

# default section start; every NSIS script has at least one section.
Section

# default section end
SectionEnd
```

The above was straight out of the NSIS docs.

Comment: ZLIB_W32 is the correct name.

Comment: The NSIS Sconscript still uses the older SCons name "MSVS_VERSION". SCons changed their naming at some point and MSVS and MSVC are two different things in SCons 3 IIRC.

Comment: Yeah, I tried using MSVS as well but the last version it supports is 8 I believe.   Also tried MSVC_USE_SCRIPT=None while in a VS2012 command prompt (per the scons docs) but it didn't work either).   All othose commands say they have to be set in the Environment call and it looks to me like nsis doesn't pass them into the call (hence my modification).

Comment: MSVC_USE_SCRIPT=None is a SCons thing that NSIS does not really support unless you do `mstoolkit=yes MSVC_USE_SCRIPT=None` (which then does not care if you have a "toolkit" or not, it just wants cl.exe in %path% etc)

Comment: The difference of a initial `_` in a function name is probably some compiler setting or something related to how the function is exported (extern "C" etc.). NSIS tends to be built with old compilers, the older the better. But I find it rather strange that if you build both the .dll and .lib yourself they are still incompatible!

Comment: For the "3 unresolved externals" error, are you sure the linker actually finds the .lib? Try adding /VERBOSE:LIB and/or /VERBOSE:UNUSEDLIBS to APPEND_LINKFLAGS?

Comment: Do you have the amd64 compiler installed for the MSVC you're installing?  You can see debug log for MSVC config by setting SCONS_MSCOMMON_DEBUG in your shell to a file and then looking in that file.  If you pastebin it and post a log here that'd be helpful.  Also note you need to compile nsis with the same version of MSVC as a prebuilt ZLIB was.

Comment: @Anders /VERBOSE:UNUSEDLIBS helped here.  It told me the zlib lib was being ignored.  And after going back to rebuilding zlib and retracing steps, I have no idea how I got to the point where I was yesterday.  One thing is the same, neither the downloaded zlib-1.2.8-amd64 nor my zlib-1.2.7-amd64 compiles work and both fail with the same linker error (see edit).  Do you know what CallProc2 is?

Comment: @bdbaddog I'm fairly certain I have everything installed as far as VS is concerned.  Afterall, my app is x64 currently, i'm now working on building a x64 installer for it.  Thanks for the tip on zlib building with the same compiler, I'm not 100% certain that is true since I'm able to build the x86 nsis using the pre-built libs which likely weren't built with VS2012.  However, I am building my own zlib x64 as well just in case.  Thanks for your help btw, a lot of your tips about using scons has come in helpful throughout this process!

Comment: @kinar CallProc2 is a assembly function in the system plugin. You can skip building that plug-in for now but issues with Scons and the .S vs .sx extensions are not uncommon because Scons changed their meaning at some point IIRC. NSIS x86 lib was probably built by VS6 and amd64 by 2005ish.

Comment: @Anders what issues is SCons having with .S and .sx? Is .sx another assembly file suffix that SCons is not recognizing currently?

Comment: @bdbaddog I don't remember the details but it might have been a change from .Sx to .sx (case change) or something that broke at some point. NSIS supports MS and GCC and we need the .S file to be pre-processed by a C compiler. We have a .sx file that simply includes the .S file to pull this off for both compilers but even with that we are still doing some TryCompile tests to figure out which file to add to the target.

Comment: @Anders - if you bring that issue over to the SCons users mailing list or the irc or discord channel we'll try to help resolve.

Comment: @Anders what is your dev toolset for building NSIS/zlib?  At this point, I really just need to get it done so I can use it.  I might revisit trying to get it to work in VS2012 (or newer) later but I can likely duplicate whatever is necessary.

Comment: The official 32-bit release is VS6 but I know most versions should work, the most recent I have tested is VS2017. For 64-bit I used the Vista WDK (IIRC). But if CallProc2 is the only issue left you can just use the cheat I added to my answer.

Comment: Ahh, I missed your edit there.  Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: You probably don't need genpat, add SKIPUTILS=VPatch/Source/GenPat and/or SKIPMISC=VPatch. "Error: reading stub" usually means it can't find the stub file. I usually build with something like `scons ... PREFIX=c:\nsis install` so that it just copies the finished files to PREFIX without build the release installer, this is enough to run the compiler and tools.

Comment: @kinar can you share x64 build please?

Comment: @Digika unfortunately, no.  I never got it completely working and the company abandoned NSIS for an off the shelf product that already builds x64 installers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My environment:

- cl.exe:
  `Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.24.28316 for x64`
- nsis version: `3.06.1`
- zlib: `Zlib-1.2.8-win64-AMD64`

I modified `SCons/Tool/masm.py`:

```
C:\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\SCons-4.0.1-py3.7.egg\SCons\Tool>diff -c masm.old.py masm.py
*** masm.old.py Fri Oct 09 22:02:45 2020
--- masm.py     Fri Oct 09 21:58:06 2020
***************
*** 61,66 ****
--- 61,68 ----
          shared_obj.add_emitter(suffix, SCons.Defaults.SharedObjectEmitter)

      env['AS']        = 'ml'
+     if env.get('TARGET_ARCH')=='amd64':
+         env['AS']   = 'ml64'
      env['ASFLAGS']   = SCons.Util.CLVar('/nologo')
      env['ASPPFLAGS'] = '$ASFLAGS'
      env['ASCOM']     = '$AS $ASFLAGS /c /Fo$TARGET $SOURCES'
```

Also modified `nsis-3.06.1-src\Contrib\System\SConscript` as follows:

```
C:\dev\nsis-3.06.1-src\Contrib\System>diff -c SConscript.old SConscript
*** SConscript.old      Fri Oct 09 22:06:31 2020
--- SConscript          Fri Oct 09 19:17:40 2020
***************
*** 4,9 ****
--- 4,10 ----
        Source/Buffers.c
        Source/Plugin.c
        Source/System.c
+       Source/Call-amd64.S
  """)

  libs = Split("""
```

Then `C:\dev\nsis-3.06.1-src>scons TARGET_ARCH=amd64` ended successfully.

Comment: happy to give you an upvote here and even mark this as an answer since it sounds like it's farther than I ever ended up getting.  Unfortunately, I ran out of patience and abandoned NSIS (after using it for 15+ years) over this issue so I can't verify it works :)

Answer (score 2):

I have

```
\zlib1.dll
\include\zconf.h
\include\zlib.h
\lib\libzdll.a
\lib\zdll.lib
\lib\zlib.lib
```

You can get pre-built zlib for NSIS [here](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Zlib).

In the past I have actually used Process Monitor to figure out which file SCons is looking for, that sadly seems to be the fastest way to find out.

Regarding CallProc2. Add "System" to SKIPPLUGINS to get past this issue to make sure everything else compiles. CallProc2 is implemented in the amd64 .S file and used by system.c. You need the 64-bit Microsoft assembler detected correctly to build the .S file.

If you only need to compile NSIS once then you can cheat; Open a Visual Studio command prompt and execute `ml64.exe /c Call-amd64.S` and then copy the .obj file to the same build directory as system.obj and run Scons again.

To do it properly you need to investigate why Scons is not compiling the .S file. Could be a configuration issue or a bug in the related Sconscript file.

Comment: Did you check scons's config.log generated when it's running configure logic?

Comment: @bdbaddog I did not compile anything now, I just looked at the file I have and I know they work. I'm sure config.log can be helpful but I often forget it exists.

Comment: @Anders It appears (using procmon) that scons is failing to find the following files in my setup: libzdll.a, zdll.lib, lib.dll.a.   I suspect that the zdll.lib is just scons checking for another possible name for zlib1.lib (but it did find zlib1.lib as well).  However, if so (meaning my setup has satisfied that requirement), that means that the only thing failing are .a files which are GCC specific intermediate files (no way to generate those with VS).  I'll play around with the downloads in your link to see if I can get by with that  but I'd like to find a pure VS solution (so it's cleaner).

Comment: I assume you don't need the .a file but the zip from the NSIS Wiki presumably supports both MSVC and GCC.

Comment: @Anders I was able to figure out what scons was looking using the config.log that bdbaddog recommended.  scons wants the lib for zlib1.dll to be zdll.lib instead of zlib1.lib.  Unfortunately that results in linker errors as well. 
 And unfortunately that zip from the NSIS wiki results in the same linking errors (see edit).

Comment: OK, it appears that I now have an x64 NSIS exe without the System plugin (not 100% positive I don't need this yet but I'll accept the progress for now).  The Cheat method did not work for me (ml64 built an object file but copying that next to the system.obj didn't resolve the Callproc2 error).  With that said, On to the next step for now.  actually using the compiled exe to compile an NSIS script (see edit).